# Flex-Basis with Percentage not working in Parent Flex Container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, percentage

I want the .web-app flex container's children (.web-app__header, .web-app__tools, .web-app__garden) to take up 10%, 10% and 60% respectively with any remaining space split evenly between them and the gaps. On mobile devices the .web-app element will have a flex-direction of column so I can use gap to create some spacing between its children.

I tried using flex-basis to make this work but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Can anyone provide any advice on how I can make this work? I don't want to use flex and remove the flex-basis as I want those precise percentages (even if they are a little bigger since they grow to take up remaining space).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <main class="web-app">
        <header class="web-app__header">
            <p>Header Section</p>
        </header>
        <div class="web-app__tools">
            <P>Tools Section</P>
        </div>
        <div class="web-app__garden">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --font-stack-titiles: Kalam, sans-serif;
    --light-green: rgb(227, 248, 227);
}

*,*::before,*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: url('../images/garden-pergola.jpg') no-repeat center/cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.web-app {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    min-width: 80%;
    min-height: 90%;
}

.web-app__header, .web-app__tools, .web-app__garden {
    background-color: var(--light-green);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.web-app__header {
    flex-basis: 10%;
}

.web-app__tools {
    flex-basis: 10%;
}

.web-app__garden {
    flex-basis: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `min-height` to `height` on parent (.web-app).
That is because **.web-app**'s height is undetermined when you use min-height on it and percentage of undetermined is meaningless

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Appreciate the help.